# Apple Keyboard may be broken.. Any way to be sure?

Tags: mac, keyboard

Well, I "cleaned" my Apple keyboard (2010 model). I used a wet rag to clean the well-used keys. It looks great but it doesn't work. I hate to toss it if I can fix it. Is it possible that I've pressed a combination that has deactivated the keyboard?

I am traveling but have the kb with me. Is there any kind of hardware test I can perform. I know the device has power as I can plug in a mouse to the USB port and the mouse works.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a keyboard trace has been damaged by water, it's practically impossible to fix them.  You're better off buying a new keyboard.

It's not the best news, but once a keyboard has been damaged by liquid, there's very little chance they will work again.

For cleaning your keyboard, I'd recommend isopropyl alcohol pads.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I was afraid of that, but thought I should check before tossing it. I wont use that hydrochloric again :)

Comment: @DavidDelMonte whoa! I hope that wasn't hydrochloric acid.... +1 for the isopropyl alcohol tip.

Comment: just kidding... i miss my keyboard. I am traveling and have to put up with something that must have been made before typewriters.. bleh.